# hide all elements onblur jquery but dont hide it while on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a multiple inputs with the same class "z"

```
<input type=text class=z>
<input type=text class=z>
<input type=text class=z>
<input type=text class=z>
```

and my jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.z').blur(function(){
        $('.z').hide();
    });
});
```

I want to hide all these elements if i lose focus in ALL of them. but I don't want to hide them all while I'm on focus each one of these element. The PROBLEM is, after typing on the first element, when I go to the next element, it automatically hide. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).show();` to make the current element visible and hiding rest of elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.z').blur(function(){
        $('.z').hide();
        $(this).show();
    });
});
```

You can exclude the current element from selector for hiding the elements using `.not` like  `$('.z').not(this).hide();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.z').blur(function(){
            $('.z').not(this).hide();       
      });
});
```

**Edit** based on change in OP

You can add attribute to store if element lost focus and use it determine if all elements have lost focus.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/kvsGe/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.z').blur(function(){
        $(this).attr('lostFocus', 'true');
        if($('.z').length == $('.z[lostFocus="true"]').length)
             $('.z').hide();
    });
});
```

**Note** add quotes to the attributes of your html elements as shown below.

```
<input type="text" class="z">
<input type="text" class="z">
<input type="text" class="z">
<input type="text" class="z">
```

Comment: im sorry. i editted my question. i want to hide all of them if i lose all focus to them. (sorry for my english)

Comment: what if. i only focus in only one element? and hide it all onblur.

Comment: because based on your code. i need to lose all the focus on all the elements before all of it will hide. what if only one. or what if two?

Comment: You can change condition to something like if($('.z[lostFocus="true"]').length == 2)

Comment: oh im sorry. you don't get me. i mean. it's not about the length on how many element i have. it's just, as long as i'm on focus on all of this element. what if the user only wants to input two elements, what if the another user wants to input 1 element, what if the other is 3, or one. then if they lose focus. or click somewhere on the page or something, that's the time it will hide.

Comment: You can not read mind of user that how many inputs he want but you have to decide how you want user to give you input